# Calling a jquery function from php

Tags: php, jquery, function, call

I've got a jQuery function that triggers when the selected option from a select element changes, its a function that is applied to the select element when it have a specific class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{       
    $('.acompanante').on('change', function(event) 
    {   
       //my code
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is my select element code:

```
<select class="acompanante" name="acompanante_anterior" id="<?php echo "$i" ?>">
  <option value="0" ><?php echo $txt_nuevo_acompanante;?></option>
  ....
</select>
```

How do I call the jQuery `.change()` event of the select element from PHP?

Comment: What do you mean from php? Do you mean on page load?

Comment: i want to call the function after i create the dropdownlist. when it changes the jquery function fills a form with all the customer info. I want to load the customer's info in the form if a customer is preselected.

Comment: Thats on page load. `created` really doesnt mean as much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change):

```
$('.acompanante').change(function() {
    alert('change() called.');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't call it from PHP and you don't need it. jQuery doesn't see the PHP, but only the rendered HTML.

So you can just bind it as normal, in this case use the class.

```
$('.acompanante').change(function(){
    this  // the dropdown which changed
});
```

Within that, you can use `$(this)` to see which dropdown it is.

Want to call javascript from PHP, let PHP render the JavaScript to do so:

```
<script>
    <?
       echo 'javascriptFunction();';
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for the 'You can't call it from PHP and you don't need it jQuery doesn't see the PHP'... There should be a FAQ/tutorial somewhere explaining the difference of scripts running on the server and on a local machine (in a browser)!

Comment: @vager there is now! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269305/looking-for-a-canonical-answer-to-web-development-language-relationships-and-flo?cb=1

Answer (score 1):

You want to execute your function on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{       
    $('.acompanante').on('change', fillDropdown);
    fillDropdown.call($('.acompanante'));
});

function fillDropdown(event)
{

}
</script>
```

Some trickery is involved to make `this` be the jquery object, which is the default behaviour for jQuery. That is what the fn.Call does.